# ng-show disturbing div layout - angularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, single-page-application, ng-show

I am using `ng-show="!notesOpened"` to hide a div if the notesOpened variable is true. However when hidden it messes up layout. Is there a way to make ng-show act in the same way as the css property `visibility:hidden`? so that all div elements around the div being hidden stay in the same place

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`ng-hide` uses the same property that you're referring to, i.e. `display: none`.

If you need to achieve this, you need to use `visibility: hidden;`

For that you can use the `ng-class` attribute.

eg: `ng-class="{'vis-hidden': notesOpened==true}"`

```
  .vis-hidden{
     visibility: hidden;
  }
```

Answer (score 16):

I have got this working

> ng-style="{visibility: notesOpened && 'visible' || 'hidden'}"

Answer (score 3):

You should try `ng-class` instead so you can give the div a class which only do `display:none`

Comment: there is no such thing as `display: hidden`, only `display: none` and `visibility: hidden`